# can jquery only get numbers like php gets number using (int)?

Tags: php, jquery, integer, int

Is there a way jquery can only get numbers like how php can get numbers by using (int)?

If I'm trying to get a text that has string and numbers

```
<div class='selector'>(4)</div>

$('.selector').text().int();
```

is there anything similar to that  where it should obtain only the number 4?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you aware that casting any string containing non-decimal values produces unexpected results in php ?

Comment: yes I'm aware of that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[parseInt()](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/convert2.htm) should do the trick. Examples (from the linked page):

```
parseInt('123.45')  // 123
parseInt('77')      // 77
parseInt('077',10)  // 77
parseInt('77',8)    // 63  (= 7 + 7*8)
parseInt('077')     // 63  (= 7 + 7*8)
parseInt('77',16)   // 119 (= 7 + 7*16)
parseInt('0x77')    // 119 (= 7 + 7*16)
parseInt('099')     // 0 (9 is not an octal digit)
parseInt('99',8)    // NaN (0 in very old browsers e.g. MSIE 3.0)
parseInt('0.1e6')   // 0
parseInt('ZZ',36)   // 1295 (= 35 + 35*36)
```

Of course, you can put variables inside `parseInt()` as well as strings.

As zerkms says in the comments, you don't actually *need* jQuery to do this. JavaScript has more functionality than jQuery would have you believe ;-)

Comment: i dont think it works for me. If the number changes dynamically, this wouldn't work.

Comment: @zerk So much jQuery! Also, be happy I didn't reference W3Schools :-P

Comment: @andrew You can put variables inside `parseInt()` too, or do you mean something else?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not really getting it. It seems like I would need to input a value into parseInt(), but I'm trying various things in my code and its not working. I've tried to put ( `if var selector = $('.selector').text()` ) `parseInt(selector)` to just get the 4, its not working. What I mean by dynamic is if the number changes instead of me inputting a static value into the function.

Comment: Um, no. `parseInt()` takes an argument; it's not a prototype. Try this: `var selector = parseInt($('.selector').text());`.

Comment: that gives me NaN because I have "()" in there

Comment: You have brackets in _where_? Having `$('.selector').text()` inside `parseInt()` is fine - `parseInt()` will operate on the value _returned by_ `parseInt($('.selector').text());`. May I suggest a basic JavaScript tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

In javascript there is a function named parseInt().